# Baby Rudin Th. 5.8 alternate proof.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm currently working through chapter 5 of baby Rudin and came across

> **Theorem 5.8** Let $f$ be defined on $[a,b]$; if $f$ has a local maximum at a point $x\in(a,b)$, and if $f'(x)$ exists, then $f'(x)=0$.

Now, this seemed like a theorem that shouldn't be too hard to prove myself so I made an attempt before moving on:

***Proof:*** Consider $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,q)<\delta \implies f(q)\leq f(x)$. Suppose $f'$ exists, then $\lim_{t\rightarrow x} \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$ exists. Let $d(t,x)<\delta$, then $f(t)-f(x)$ is nonpositive. Suppose that $f(t)-f(x)<0$, then $$\lim_{t\rightarrow x^+} \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\neq\lim_{t\rightarrow x^-} \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x},$$
which contradicts the existence of $f'$. Therefore $f'=0$

But I'm not entirely sure that I'm allowed to do everything I do. Specifically, I'm not certain whether the use of unequal right and left limit is allowed in the way I do it here.

Comment: When you assume that $f(t) - f(x) < 0$, are you assuming that for all $t$ near $x$, for at least one $t$, or something else?

Comment: You find a contradiction and then you conclude that $f'=0$. I reckon you mean $f'(x)=0$. But such conclusion can only be made if the contradiction is based on the hypothese $f'(x)\neq0$. In the proof you do not make that hypothese.

Comment: @user49640 For all, based on the definition of a local maximum.

Comment: @MitchellFaas That's not really the negation of what you're trying to prove. In fact, if $f(t) = -t^2$, then it will certainly be the case that $f(t) - f(0)$ is negative for $t \ne 0$. Since you know that $f'(x)$ exists, the negation of what you're trying to prove would be to assume $f'(x) \ne 0$. $f'(x)$ is defined as a certain limit, but a nonzero function can have a zero limit. This is the case when you write down the limit defining $f'(0)$ in the example I gave.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proof of Fermat’s Theorem.

Paul's Online Math Notes

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DerivativeAppsProofs.aspx

Comment: This might be suitable to place as a comment. Definitely not as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I don't have 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: Rudin's proof is much neater. This was just me trying to prove it before actually reading the given proof.

Comment: @Mitchell Faas Actually I'd say that the proof given above is more explicit than Rudin's (having just looked at both). I like Rudin's book quite a lot myself, but it's definitely important to consult other sources - like the one Ray gave - if something he does has you confused. Rudin will sometimes condense non-trivial steps in ways that the reader is expected to unpack, and you can miss important details if you aren't careful.